# val.replace(/[^a-zA-Z_-0-9]/g, '') produce SyntaxError: invalid range in character class

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace all chars which are not match with range `a-zA-Z_-0-9`. So I do `val.replace(/[^a-zA-Z_-0-9]/g, '')` but get error. How can I bit this?
Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to include the minus sign "-" in the character class, you have to put it into the end of range:

```
val.replace(/[^a-zA-Z_0-9-]/g, '')
```

Answer (score 4):

You expect that `-` character to be parsed as being literal, but it is in fact parsed as a range: `_-0` means `_` to `0`, just like `a-z` means `a` to `z`. However, since `_` has a higher character code than `0`, you get an error.

In your case, just escape it: `\-`. This is parsed as the `-` character.

Comment: Backslash escaping characters inside a bracket list is not allowed in the POSIX regex standard, so I'd be wary to use it.

Comment: @SimonRichter: The JavaScript regex flavor derives from Perl, not POSIX.  Backslash escaping works just fine (but moving the hyphen to the end is neater).

Answer (score 4):

I would prefer this regex:

```
val.replace(/[^\w-]+/gi, "");
```

Comment: forgot about digit 
need smth like this: `val.replace(/[^\w^\d-]+/gi, "");`  or mb `val.replace(/[\W\D-]+/gi, "");`  but need to test.

Answer (score 4):

[The `-` character is treated as a literal character if it is the last or the first (after the `^`) character within the brackets.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

Comment: Not only, it is treated as a literal `-` wherever it cannot form a range, e.g. next to a shorthand character class as in `[A-Z-\s-\d]`.

Answer (score 2):

You have a bad range, remove the `-` between `_` and the number range and put it at the end or at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
val.replace(/[^a-zA-Z_0-9-]/g, '');
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the "-"

```
val.replace(/[^a-zA-Z_\-0-9]/g, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z_0-9-]/g, ''));
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".