# How to cancel CSS effect in Responsive Website Footer menu?

Tags: wordpress, css, responsive-design

I have been using this tutorial (http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/10/24/creative-css3-animation-menus/) to build my footer menu at http://kikidesign.net. It's only for desktop version. I'm trying to edit the footer menu for mobile version and to do so, I tried to cancel the effect in @media.

Desktop version

```
.ca-menu {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.ca-menu li {
    float: left;
    width: 22.916666667%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background: none;
    margin-right: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 300ms linear;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms linear;
    transition: all 300ms linear;
}
.ca-menu li:hover {
    z-index:999;  
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);  
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);  
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);   
    -o-transform: scale(1.2); 
    transform: scale(1.2); 
}
.ca-menu li:hover .aboutimg, .ca-menu li:hover .contactimg, .ca-menu li:hover .downloadimg, .ca-menu li:hover .facebookimg {
    color: #ffffff;
    /**font-size: 30px;**/
    opacity:0.3;
}
.ca-main{
    font-family: 'PrintClearlyRegular';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 1.75em;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -ms-transition: all 200ms linear;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.ca-menu li:hover .ca-main{
    color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-animation: smallToBig 300ms ease;
    -moz-animation: smallToBig 300ms ease;
    -ms-animation: smallToBig 300ms ease;
    font-size: 2.1em;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0; 
    margin: 0;
}
.ca-menu li a{
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
}
@-webkit-keyframes smallToBig{
    from {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes smallToBig{
    from {
        -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
    }
    to {
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes smallToBig{
    from {
        -ms-transform: scale(0.1);
    }
    to {
        -ms-transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

mobile version (@media only screen and (max-width: 480px))

```
.ca-menu li {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background: none;
    margin-right: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
    -ms-transition: none;
    transition: none;
}
.ca-menu li:hover {
    z-index:0;  
    -webkit-transform: none;  
    -moz-transform: none;  
    -ms-transform: none;   
    -o-transform: none; 
    transform: none; 
}
.ca-menu li:hover .aboutimg, .ca-menu li:hover .contactimg, .ca-menu li:hover .downloadimg, .ca-menu li:hover .facebookimg {
    color: #ffffff;
    /**font-size: 30px;**/
    opacity: 1;
}
.ca-main{
    font-family: 'PrintClearlyRegular';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 1.75em;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
    -ms-transition: none;
    transition: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.ca-menu li:hover .ca-main{
    color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-animation: none;
    -moz-animation: none;
    -ms-animation: none;
    font-size: 1.75em;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0; 
    margin: 0;
}
```

However, when I test it out in mobile version, the links keep jumping up. I don't want the links to jump up or anything like that but I couldn't fix it! What do I need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is within the .ca-main in the mobile version. You didn't set a "margin: 0", and because it is an H3, it already has a margin. So, when you hover the li, the margin gets removed and you get the "jump" effect. It has nothing to do with transitions or animations.

BTW, you are getting a syntax error in your custom.js line 14.

Comment: Thanks, got it to work!    BTW, custom.js is for the contact page and it works fine. What was the error?   the line 14 is 'var emailReg = /^([w-.]+@([w-]+.)+[w-]{2,4})?$/;'

Comment: It is showing this exact error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142829/val-replace-a-za-z-0-9-g-produce-syntaxerror-invalid-range-in-charact. All the information to solve the problem is there.

Comment: the link you gave me about this error was talking about replacing an line. How is it related to this error? Please explain it fully to me. Also I am now looking for the tutorial that I used few months ago to build this contact form without any wordpress plugin.

Comment: Try this: `/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;`

Comment: found the tutorial. It's http://trevordavis.net/blog/wordpress-jquery-contact-form-without-a-plugin. BTW, I put what you wrote in the line 14 but my Adobe Dreamweaver software returned another error on line 30 (return false;)

Comment: You didn't copy the entire tutorial's code. You are missing the `if(!hasError)`. Here you have the complete code: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=74awYWgv). If it doesn't work, change the original regexp for the one I posted.

Comment: Okay, I changed it. Looks like everything is fine, I think? How did you know that the contact page had this error?

Comment: I'm Gandalf, and errors SHALL NOT PASS! I have installed [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) and in the console tab you can see javascript errors. Great tool.

Answer (score 0):

you can write media query for different screen and give css style for all screen.

example of media query

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    //your changed code here;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 950px) {
    //your changed style here;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    //your changed style here;
}
```

different screen size  you can find from net
or if you want to make dropdown box at any size screen you can referred this link
http://tinynav.viljamis.com/

Comment: She's already using media queries. The problem is that she doesn't know what's wrong with CSS inside them.

Comment: Thanks, but I am already using this method, but I only found out that the coding from the desktop (@media screen and (max-width: 1024px)) carries over to other @media screens unless you specific an different effect for certain area in different versions.