# Replace letters with dashes

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

Very very junior, apologies if isn't appropriate.

I'm trying to replace all letters in a string with dashes, and my code works if it's only one character, but doesn't with more than one.I've tried a for loop, but doesn't work either.
I've been reading other threads, like:  [Other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142829/val-replace-a-za-z-0-9-g-produce-syntaxerror-invalid-range-in-charact) but cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong, and I've been reading for a while now.
Could anyone help me out?

This is my code so far:

```
function replaceLettersWithDashes(str) {
  /* This function will receive a string with a mix of characters. It should return the string with all letters replaced by dashes ('-').

    For example 'You like cake' should return '--- ---- ----', and 'Tree 4, 6, 8' should return '---- 4, 6, 8'.

    */

     return str.replace(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/g , '-');


}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove `^` and `$` anchors. I think you don't need `+` quantifier too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regex `/[a-zA-Z]/g`
The reason your code print one dash is because you are replacing the whole word with `-` . `[a-zA-Z]+` means word with letters.

In this regex `/[a-zA-Z]/g` [a-zA-z] means any one letter and `g`(global) means search all possible match(not stop on first one)

```js
str='You like cake';
console.log(str.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g , '-'));
```

Comment: Ah ok, get it now. Makes so much sense!!

Answer (score 5):

You could search for a single letter and replace it with this regular expression, which looks for a letter and replace every letter with a dash. The flags `'g'` and `'i'` are for global search and case insensitive search.

```
/[a-z]/gi
```

If you use a `+` or `*` as quantifier, you get all following letters and replace it with a single dash, which is not wanted.

```js
function replaceLettersWithDashes(str) {
    return str.replace(/[a-z]/gi , '-');
}

console.log(replaceLettersWithDashes('You like cake'));
console.log(replaceLettersWithDashes('Tree 4, 6, 8'));
```

Comment: Done, thanks very much. I'm not very familiar with regex, definitely need to go deeper in it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

use this pattern of regex `/[a-z]/gi`, 
`\D` means something like “not digit”. It will let you with a very compact code.
See snippet below

```js
function replaceLettersWithDashes(str) {
  var newStr = str.replace(/[a-z]/gi, "-");     
 console.log(newStr);
 return newStr;
};

replaceLettersWithDashes("abcdef100abcdi50");
```

But, if you need just characters (letting white-space and spaces), then go ahead with your regex pattern, just adding the `g` as said in the comments of your question. :D

Comment: Why should OP use `\D` while clearly says: "letters"?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick example !!!

```html
<p id="input"></p>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var str ='asdfdfgfdgdfg';
let res = str.replace(/[A-Za-z]?/g,'-');
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = str;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return str.replace(/\w/gi , '-')
```

Comment: please add more description